# Signature of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

If $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$, we define its signature as the triple $(s^+,s^-,s^0)$, where $s^+,s^-,s^0\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$ denotes respectively the number of eigenvalues $>0,<0,=0$.

How can we define the signature of a $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: It's typical to define it for hermitian matrices only.

Comment: How can we do this?

Comment: Exactly the same way.

Comment: But how can we be sure to find some real eigenvalue? Maybe we are considering also the possibility to have $s^+,s^-,s^0=0$?

Comment: [Hermitian matrices have real eigenvalues](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hermitian_Matrix_has_Real_Eigenvalues/Proof_2).

Comment: However, why the downvote?